# Hosting raster tiles on GeoServer?

Tags: raster, geoserver, tiles, references

I am new to GIS world. I am trying to host raster images (TIFF) which I need to convert in tiles and host on GeoServer and prepare the service URL so that any user using that service zoom to any location, the service will get the tiles of that location and display it.

I am able to convert the raster image to tiles which create multiple folders and put the tiles into it using gdal2tiles. Now I am not getting the option to upload that folder in the GeoServer to achieve my task.

Can anyone explain what I need to do or guide me to any tutorial where I can study and achieve my task?

Comment: So you need a WMS or WCS which uses GeoTIFF as input You should find all information in the GeoServer docs

Comment: I have tried searching but I didn't get any solution. Can you guide me to some URL for doing it.

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/index.html and https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/index.html would be god places to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an [image pyramid](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagepyramid.html) layer, there is a [full tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) in the manual as well.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try to implement this on Monday in office

Comment: Hello I have implemented exactly which its shows in the documentaion but when I am viewing it . Its showing blank.

Comment: If you have a new question please ask it directly - make sure to include details of the data you are using and the exact text of the error message that is in the GeoServer log file

Comment: I already did that : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328089/implementing-pyramid-plugin-in-geoserver