# Implementing Pyramid plugin in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, image-pyramids

I am trying to use the Pyramid plugin for viewing the raster tiles in the WMS service. I have done exactly same as its given in documentation [URL](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html)

Except while converting my TIFF image I have not used `-co "COMPRESS=JPEG"` as I am getting the list of warnings. And its not compulsory as per the documentation. On store also I have given the correct path. In the path folder 0 has been created with all the tiles and shapefile. And I have changed the setting exactly what its mentioned in the documentation. But still when I am trying to view in the OpenLayers its not coming with the tiles. Its opening a blank page with settings

You can download the image from here :
[Tiff Image](http://gisxperts.aabsys.com/world/0100-0.tif)

What I am doing wrong? I have my TIFF image where I am doing these operation.

Command which ran to convert raster images to tiles:

`gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -targetDir bmpyramid bmreduced.tiff`

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error message. when I am viewing through Layer Preview -> Openlayer. Its showing blank square with some settings. I hope you got my point

Comment: @IanTurton Do you have any solution  ? Why I am facing this.

Comment: if there is no error I have no clue - see http://geoserver.org/support/ for more support options

Comment: works fine for me - what did you put in for Declared SRS?

Comment: Also it may help others see what's wrong if you add the exact commands you ran

Comment: @IanTurton I have randomly selected EPSG:2106. What should I give ?

Comment: 3857 to match your rasters

Comment: thanks man I got it!! How did you find it ? I am new to GIS world.

Comment: http://prj2epsg.org/search